# One Page Checkout won't go to the second step in Magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, checkout-page

I moved my client's old magento website from one server to another but now the one-page checkout won't work.

I'm getting the following error when I press "continue" in the "Billing Section"

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in <b>/homepages/29/d849973409/htdocs/burlaptablecloth/public_html/index.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />
{"goto_section":"shipping_method","update_section":{"name":"shipping-method","html":"    <dl class=\"sp-methods\">\n                <dt>United States Postal Service<\/dt>\n        <dd>\n            <ul>\n                                            <li>\n                                                                   <input name=\"shipping_method\" type=\"radio\" value=\"usps_Priority Mail\" id=\"s_method_usps_Priority Mail\" class=\"radio\"\/>\n\n                        \n                                                <label for=\"s_method_usps_Priority Mail\">Priority Mail                                                                        <span class=\"price\">$25.97<\/span>                                                <\/label>\n                                   <\/li>\n                        <\/ul>\n        <\/dd>\n            <dt>United Parcel Service<\/dt>\n        <dd>\n            <ul>\n                                            <li>\n                                                                   <input name=\"shipping_method\" type=\"radio\" value=\"ups_03\" id=\"s_method_ups_03\" class=\"radio\"\/>\n\n                        \n                                                <label for=\"s_method_ups_03\">UPS Ground                                                                        <span class=\"price\">$23.14<\/span>                                                <\/label>\n                                   <\/li>\n                                            <li>\n                                                                   <input name=\"shipping_method\" type=\"radio\" value=\"ups_12\" id=\"s_method_ups_12\" class=\"radio\"\/>\n\n                        \n                                                <label for=\"s_method_ups_12\">UPS Three-Day Select                                                                        <span class=\"price\">$36.42<\/span>                                                <\/label>\n                                   <\/li>\n                                            <li>\n                                                                   <input name=\"shipping_method\" type=\"radio\" value=\"ups_02\" id=\"s_method_ups_02\" class=\"radio\"\/>\n\n                        \n                                                <label for=\"s_method_ups_02\">UPS Second Day Air                                                                        <span class=\"price\">$40.20<\/span>                                                <\/label>\n                                   <\/li>\n                                            <li>\n                                                                   <input name=\"shipping_method\" type=\"radio\" value=\"ups_01\" id=\"s_method_ups_01\" class=\"radio\"\/>\n\n                        \n                                                <label for=\"s_method_ups_01\">UPS Next Day Air                                                                        <span class=\"price\">$69.01<\/span>                                                <\/label>\n                                   <\/li>\n                                            <li>\n                                                                   <input name=\"shipping_method\" type=\"radio\" value=\"ups_14\" id=\"s_method_ups_14\" class=\"radio\"\/>\n\n                        \n                                                <label for=\"s_method_ups_14\">UPS Next Day Air Early A.M.                                                                        <span class=\"price\">$226.28<\/span>                                                <\/label>\n                                   <\/li>\n                        <\/ul>\n        <\/dd>\n        <\/dl>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\/\/<![CDATA[\n            var shippingCodePrice = {'usps_Priority Mail':25.97,'ups_03':23.14,'ups_12':36.42,'ups_02':40.2,'ups_01':69.01,'ups_14':226.28};\n    \n    $$('input[type=\"radio\"][name=\"shipping_method\"]').each(function(el){\n        Event.observe(el, 'click', function(){\n            if (el.checked == true) {\n                var getShippingCode = el.getValue();\n                                    var newPrice = shippingCodePrice[getShippingCode];\n                    if (!lastPrice) {\n                        lastPrice = newPrice;\n                        quoteBaseGrandTotal += newPrice;\n                    }\n                    if (newPrice != lastPrice) {\n                        quoteBaseGrandTotal += (newPrice-lastPrice);\n                        lastPrice = newPrice;\n                    }\n                                checkQuoteBaseGrandTotal = quoteBaseGrandTotal;\n                return false;\n            }\n       });\n    });\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n"},"allow_sections":["shipping"],"duplicateBillingInfo":"true"}
```

The code is using: `../magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

```
 public function saveBillingAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled() && !$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
            $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);

            if (isset($data['email'])) {
                $data['email'] = trim($data['email']);
            }
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);
            
            if (!isset($result['error'])) {
                if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'payment-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                    );
                } elseif (isset($data['use_for_shipping']) && $data['use_for_shipping'] == 1) {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping_method';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'shipping-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getShippingMethodsHtml()
                    );

                    $result['allow_sections'] = array('shipping');
                    $result['duplicateBillingInfo'] = 'true';
                } else {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping';
                }
            }
            


            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: You have a customized `index.php` at the Magento root. You need to take a look at it and fix this `preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`.

Comment: The weird thing is I never made any changes in ```index.php```. I simply transferred the whole project from one place to other. I assumed it had something to do with php version because the old server was using 5.3 but on my new shared hosting there is no support for 5.3 instead, I used 5.4. It didn't make sense to me but I added an additional check before ```preg_match()``` to skip arrays because every other method seem to be working correctly. So now checkout and everything else is working again.